# Translate nucleic acid sequence into its corresponding amino acid sequence

Tags: performance, algorithm, go, bioinformatics, multiprocessing

### Goal of the program

The goal of the program is to translate a nucleic acid sequence into its corresponding amino acid sequence. The nucleic sequences
have to be formatted in a specific format called [`fasta`](https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?CMD=Web&PAGE_TYPE=BlastDocs&DOC_TYPE=BlastHelp). There is an existing implementation of this program in C here: [emboss transeq](http://emboss.sourceforge.net/apps/cvs/emboss/apps/transeq.html)

#### Fasta format

A fasta file looks like this:

```
>sequenceId comment
nucleic sequence
```

for example:

```
>Seq1 [organism=Carpodacus mexicanus] [clone=6b] actin (act) mRNA, partial cds
CCTTTATCTAATCTTTGGAGCATGAGCTGGCATAGTTGGAACCGCCCTCAGCCTCCTCATCCGTGCAGAA
CCCAGTCCTGTACCAACACCTCTTCTGATTCTTCGGCCATCCAGAAGTCTATATCCTCATTTTAC

>Seq2 [organism=uncultured bacillus sp.] [isolate=A2] corticotropin (CT) gene
GGTAGGTACCGCCCTAAGNCTCCTAATCCGAGCAGAACTANGCCAACCCGGAGCCCTTCTGGGAGACGAC
AATCAACATAAAA
```

A nucleic sequence is a string composed of the letters `A`, `C`, `T`, `G`, `U`, `N`

#### Expected output

A combinaison of **3 nucleic acid**, named codon,  gives a specif amino acid, for exemple `GCT` is the code for [`Alanine`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alanine), symbolised by the letter `A`

With the Seq1 define above:

```
codon      CCT TTA TCT AAT CTT TGG AGC ATG ...
amino acid  P   L   S   N   L   W   S   M  ...
```

The expected output is:

```
>Seq1_1 [organism=Carpodacus mexicanus] [clone=6b] actin (act) mRNA, partial cds
PLSNLWSMSWHSWNRPQPPHPCRTQSCTNTSSDSSAIQKSISSFY
>Seq2_1 [organism=uncultured bacillus sp.] [isolate=A2] corticotropin (CT) gene
GRYRPKXPNPSRTXPTRSPSGRRQST*X
```

#### Specific rules

The program takes 4 parameters:

- `clean` : if true,  write STOP codon as `X` instead of `*`
- `trim` : if true, remove all `X` and `*` chars from the right end of the amino - acid sequence
- `alternative`: different way to compute reverse frame
- `frame`: a string value in `["1", "2", "3", "F", "-1", "-2", "-3", "R", "6" ]`

The frame define the position in the nucleic sequence to start from:

```
-frame 1
|-frame 2
||-frame 3
|||
CCTTTATCTAATCTTTGGAGCATGAGCTGGCATAGTTGGAACCGCCCTCAGCCTCCTCATCCGTGCAGAA
CCCAGTCCTGTACCAACACCTCTTCTGATTCTTCGGCCATCCAGAAGTCTATATCCTCATTTTAC
                                                              |||
                                                              ||-frame -1
                                                              |-frame -2
                                                              -frame -3


frame "F" = "1", "2", "3"
frame "R" = "-1", "-2", "-3"
frame "6" = "1", "2", "3", "-1", "-2", "-3"
```

In the output file, we add the frame used to the sequenceId: `sequenceId = sequenceId_frame`

For example if the program is used with `frame=6`, the expected output is

```
>Seq1_1 [organism=Carpodacus mexicanus] [clone=6b] actin (act) mRNA, partial cds
PLSNLWSMSWHSWNRPQPPHPCRTQSCTNTSSDSSAIQKSISSFY
>Seq1_2 [organism=Carpodacus mexicanus] [clone=6b] actin (act) mRNA, partial cds
LYLIFGA*AGIVGTALSLLIRAEPSPVPTPLLILRPSRSLYPHFT
>Seq1_3 [organism=Carpodacus mexicanus] [clone=6b] actin (act) mRNA, partial cds
FI*SLEHELA*LEPPSASSSVQNPVLYQHLF*FFGHPEVYILILX
>Seq1_4 [organism=Carpodacus mexicanus] [clone=6b] actin (act) mRNA, partial cds
VK*GYRLLDGRRIRRGVGTGLGSARMRRLRAVPTMPAHAPKIR*R
>Seq1_5 [organism=Carpodacus mexicanus] [clone=6b] actin (act) mRNA, partial cds
KMRI*TSGWPKNQKRCWYRTGFCTDEEAEGGSNYASSCSKD*IKX
>Seq1_6 [organism=Carpodacus mexicanus] [clone=6b] actin (act) mRNA, partial cds
*NEDIDFWMAEESEEVLVQDWVLHG*GG*GRFQLCQLMLQRLDKG
>Seq2_1 [organism=uncultured bacillus sp.] [isolate=A2] corticotropin (CT) gene
GRYRPKXPNPSRTXPTRSPSGRRQST*X
>Seq2_2 [organism=uncultured bacillus sp.] [isolate=A2] corticotropin (CT) gene
VGTALXLLIRAELXQPGALLGDDNQHKX
>Seq2_3 [organism=uncultured bacillus sp.] [isolate=A2] corticotropin (CT) gene
*VPP*XS*SEQNXANPEPFWETTINIK
>Seq2_4 [organism=uncultured bacillus sp.] [isolate=A2] corticotropin (CT) gene
LC*LSSPRRAPGWXSSARIRXLRAVPT
>Seq2_5 [organism=uncultured bacillus sp.] [isolate=A2] corticotropin (CT) gene
FMLIVVSQKGSGLA*FCSD*EX*GGTYX
>Seq2_6 [organism=uncultured bacillus sp.] [isolate=A2] corticotropin (CT) gene
FYVDCRLPEGLRVGXVLLGLGXLGRYLP
```

### Improvements

- Performance improvements
- Is the code easy to read / understand ?
- Is the code idiomatic ?

( full project with tests + flags handling is avaible on github: [gotranseq](https://github.com/feliixx/gotranseq))

**code :**

```
package transeq

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "context"
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
)

var (
    letterCode = map[byte]uint8{
        'A': aCode,
        'C': cCode,
        'T': tCode,
        'G': gCode,
        'N': nCode,
        'U': uCode,
    }
    standard = map[string]byte{
        "TTT": 'F',
        "TCT": 'S',
        "TAT": 'Y',
        "TGT": 'C',
        "TTC": 'F',
        "TCC": 'S',
        "TAC": 'Y',
        "TGC": 'C',
        "TTA": 'L',
        "TCA": 'S',
        "TAA": '*',
        "TGA": '*',
        "TTG": 'L',
        "TCG": 'S',
        "TAG": '*',
        "TGG": 'W',
        "CTT": 'L',
        "CCT": 'P',
        "CAT": 'H',
        "CGT": 'R',
        "CTC": 'L',
        "CCC": 'P',
        "CAC": 'H',
        "CGC": 'R',
        "CTA": 'L',
        "CCA": 'P',
        "CAA": 'Q',
        "CGA": 'R',
        "CTG": 'L',
        "CCG": 'P',
        "CAG": 'Q',
        "CGG": 'R',
        "ATT": 'I',
        "ACT": 'T',
        "AAT": 'N',
        "AGT": 'S',
        "ATC": 'I',
        "ACC": 'T',
        "AAC": 'N',
        "AGC": 'S',
        "ATA": 'I',
        "ACA": 'T',
        "AAA": 'K',
        "AGA": 'R',
        "ATG": 'M',
        "ACG": 'T',
        "AAG": 'K',
        "AGG": 'R',
        "GTT": 'V',
        "GCT": 'A',
        "GAT": 'D',
        "GGT": 'G',
        "GTC": 'V',
        "GCC": 'A',
        "GAC": 'D',
        "GGC": 'G',
        "GTA": 'V',
        "GCA": 'A',
        "GAA": 'E',
        "GGA": 'G',
        "GTG": 'V',
        "GCG": 'A',
        "GAG": 'E',
        "GGG": 'G',
    }
)

const (
    nCode = uint8(0)
    aCode = uint8(1)
    cCode = uint8(2)
    tCode = uint8(3)
    uCode = uint8(3)
    gCode = uint8(4)

    stopByte = '*'
    unknown  = 'X'
    // Length of the array to store code/bytes
    // uses gCode because it's the biggest uint8 of all codes
    arrayCodeSize = (uint32(gCode) | uint32(gCode)<<8 | uint32(gCode)<<16) + 1
)

func createCodeArray(clean bool) []byte {

    resultMap := map[uint32]byte{}
    twoLetterMap := map[string][]byte{}

    tmpCode := make([]uint8, 4)

    for codon, aaCode := range standard {
        // generate 3 letter code
        for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
            tmpCode[i] = letterCode[codon[i]]
        }
        // each codon is represented by an unique uint32:
        // each possible nucleotide is represented by an uint8 (255 possibility)
        // the three first bytes are the the code for each nucleotide
        // last byte is unused ( eq to uint8(0) )
        // example:
        // codon 'ACG' ==> uint32(aCode) | uint32(cCode)<<8 | uint32(gCode)<<16
        uint32Code := uint32(tmpCode[0]) | uint32(tmpCode[1])<<8 | uint32(tmpCode[2])<<16
        resultMap[uint32Code] = aaCode

        // generate 2 letter code
        codes, ok := twoLetterMap[codon[0:2]]
        if !ok {
            twoLetterMap[codon[0:2]] = []byte{aaCode}
        } else {
            twoLetterMap[codon[0:2]] = append(codes, aaCode)
        }
    }
    for twoLetterCodon, codes := range twoLetterMap {
        uniqueAA := true
        for i := 0; i < len(codes); i++ {

            if codes[i] != codes[0] {
                uniqueAA = false
            }
        }
        if uniqueAA {
            first := letterCode[twoLetterCodon[0]]
            second := letterCode[twoLetterCodon[1]]

            uint32Code := uint32(first) | uint32(second)<<8
            resultMap[uint32Code] = codes[0]
        }
    }
    // if clean is specified, we want to replace all '*' by 'X' in the output
    // sequence, so replace all occurrences of '*' directly in the ref map
    if clean {
        for k, v := range resultMap {
            if v == stopByte {
                resultMap[k] = unknown
            }
        }
    }
    r := make([]byte, arrayCodeSize)
    for k, v := range resultMap {
        r[k] = v
    }
    return r
}

func computeFrames(frameName string) (frames []int, reverse bool, err error) {

    frames = make([]int, 6)
    reverse = false

    switch frameName {
    case "1":
        frames[0] = 1
    case "2":
        frames[1] = 1
    case "3":
        frames[2] = 1
    case "F":
        for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
            frames[i] = 1
        }
    case "-1":
        frames[3] = 1
        reverse = true
    case "-2":
        frames[4] = 1
        reverse = true
    case "-3":
        frames[5] = 1
        reverse = true
    case "R":
        for i := 3; i < 6; i++ {
            frames[i] = 1
        }
        reverse = true
    case "6":
        for i := range frames {
            frames[i] = 1
        }
        reverse = true
    default:
        err = fmt.Errorf("wrong value for -f | --frame parameter: %s", frameName)
    }
    return frames, reverse, err
}

type writer struct {
    buf            *bytes.Buffer
    currentLineLen int
    bytesToTrim    int
}

func (w *writer) addByte(b byte) {
    w.buf.WriteByte(b)
    w.currentLineLen++
    if b == stopByte || b == unknown {
        w.bytesToTrim++
    } else {
        w.bytesToTrim = 0
    }
}

func (w *writer) addUnknown() {
    w.buf.WriteByte(unknown)
    w.currentLineLen++
    w.bytesToTrim++
}

func (w *writer) newLine() {
    w.buf.WriteByte('\n')
    w.currentLineLen = 0
    w.bytesToTrim++
}

const (
    // size of the buffer for writing to file
    maxBufferSize = 1024 * 1024 * 30
    // max line size for sequence
    maxLineSize = 60
    // suffixes ta add to sequence id for each frame
    suffixes = "123456"
)

// Translate read a fata file, translate each sequence to the corresponding prot sequence in the specified frame
func Translate(inputSequence io.Reader, out io.Writer, frame string, clean, trim, alternative bool) error {

    arrayCode := createCodeArray(clean)
    framesToGenerate, reverse, err := computeFrames(frame)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    fnaSequences := make(chan encodedSequence, 10)
    errs := make(chan error, 1)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    defer cancel()

    for nWorker := 0; nWorker < runtime.NumCPU(); nWorker++ {

        wg.Add(1)

        go func() {

            defer wg.Done()

            startPosition := make([]int, 3)
            w := &writer{
                buf:            bytes.NewBuffer(nil),
                bytesToTrim:    0,
                currentLineLen: 0,
            }

            for sequence := range fnaSequences {

                select {
                case <-ctx.Done():
                    return
                default:
                }

                frameIndex := 0
                startPosition[0], startPosition[1], startPosition[2] = 0, 1, 2

                idSize := int(binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(sequence[0:4]))
                nuclSeqLength := len(sequence) - idSize

            Translate:
                for _, startPos := range startPosition {

                    if framesToGenerate[frameIndex] == 0 {
                        frameIndex++
                        continue
                    }

                    // sequence id should look like
                    // >sequenceID_<frame> comment
                    idEnd := bytes.IndexByte(sequence[4:idSize], ' ')
                    if idEnd != -1 {
                        w.buf.Write(sequence[4 : 4+idEnd])
                        w.buf.WriteByte('_')
                        w.buf.WriteByte(suffixes[frameIndex])
                        w.buf.Write(sequence[4+idEnd : idSize])
                    } else {
                        w.buf.Write(sequence[4:idSize])
                        w.buf.WriteByte('_')
                        w.buf.WriteByte(suffixes[frameIndex])
                    }
                    w.newLine()

                    // if in trim mode, nb of bytes to trim (nb of successive 'X', '*' and '\n'
                    // from right end of the sequence)
                    w.bytesToTrim = 0
                    w.currentLineLen = 0

                    // read the sequence 3 letters at a time, starting at a specific position
                    // corresponding to the frame
                    for pos := startPos + 2 + idSize; pos < len(sequence); pos += 3 {

                        if w.currentLineLen == maxLineSize {
                            w.newLine()
                        }
                        // create an uint32 from the codon, to retrieve the corresponding
                        // AA from the map
                        codonCode := uint32(sequence[pos-2]) | uint32(sequence[pos-1])<<8 | uint32(sequence[pos])<<16

                        b := arrayCode[codonCode]
                        if b != byte(0) {
                            w.addByte(b)
                        } else {
                            w.addUnknown()
                        }
                    }

                    // the last codon is only 2 nucleotid long, try to guess
                    // the corresponding AA
                    if (nuclSeqLength-startPos)%3 == 2 {

                        if w.currentLineLen == maxLineSize {
                            w.newLine()
                        }
                        codonCode := uint32(sequence[len(sequence)-2]) | uint32(sequence[len(sequence)-1])<<8

                        b := arrayCode[codonCode]
                        if b != byte(0) {
                            w.addByte(b)
                        } else {
                            w.addUnknown()
                        }
                    }

                    // the last codon is only 1 nucleotid long, no way to guess
                    // the corresponding AA
                    if (nuclSeqLength-startPos)%3 == 1 {
                        if w.currentLineLen == maxLineSize {
                            w.newLine()
                        }
                        w.addUnknown()
                    }

                    if trim && w.bytesToTrim > 0 {
                        // remove the last bytesToTrim bytes of the buffer
                        // as they are 'X', '*' or '\n'
                        w.buf.Truncate(w.buf.Len() - w.bytesToTrim)
                        w.currentLineLen -= w.bytesToTrim
                    }

                    if w.currentLineLen != 0 {
                        w.newLine()
                    }
                    frameIndex++
                }

                if reverse && frameIndex < 6 {

                    // get the complementary sequence.
                    // Basically, switch
                    //   A <-> T
                    //   C <-> G
                    // N is not modified
                    for i, n := range sequence[idSize:] {

                        switch n {
                        case aCode:
                            sequence[i+idSize] = tCode
                        case tCode:
                            // handle both tCode and uCode
                            sequence[i+idSize] = aCode
                        case cCode:
                            sequence[i+idSize] = gCode
                        case gCode:
                            sequence[i+idSize] = cCode
                        default:
                            //case N -> leave it
                        }
                    }
                    // reverse the sequence
                    for i, j := idSize, len(sequence)-1; i < j; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
                        sequence[i], sequence[j] = sequence[j], sequence[i]
                    }

                    if !alternative {
                        // Staden convention: Frame -1 is the reverse-complement of the sequence
                        // having the same codon phase as frame 1. Frame -2 is the same phase as
                        // frame 2. Frame -3 is the same phase as frame 3
                        //
                        // use the matrix to keep track of the forward frame as it depends on the
                        // length of the sequence
                        switch nuclSeqLength % 3 {
                        case 0:
                            startPosition[0], startPosition[1], startPosition[2] = 0, 2, 1
                        case 1:
                            startPosition[0], startPosition[1], startPosition[2] = 1, 0, 2
                        case 2:
                            startPosition[0], startPosition[1], startPosition[2] = 2, 1, 0
                        }
                    }
                    // run the same loop, but with the reverse-complemented sequence
                    goto Translate
                }

                if w.buf.Len() > maxBufferSize {
                    _, err := out.Write(w.buf.Bytes())
                    if err != nil {
                        select {
                        case errs <- fmt.Errorf("fail to write to output file: %v", err):
                        default:
                        }
                        cancel()
                        return
                    }
                    w.buf.Reset()
                }
                pool.Put(sequence)
            }

            if w.buf.Len() > 0 {
                _, err := out.Write(w.buf.Bytes())
                if err != nil {
                    select {
                    case errs <- fmt.Errorf("fail to write to output file: %v", err):
                    default:
                    }
                    cancel()
                    return
                }
            }
        }()
    }
    readSequenceFromFasta(ctx, inputSequence, fnaSequences)

    wg.Wait()
    select {
    case err, ok := <-errs:
        if ok {
            return err
        }
    default:
    }
    return nil
}

func readSequenceFromFasta(ctx context.Context, inputSequence io.Reader, fnaSequences chan encodedSequence) {

    feeder := &fastaChannelFeeder{
        idBuffer:       bytes.NewBuffer(nil),
        commentBuffer:  bytes.NewBuffer(nil),
        sequenceBuffer: bytes.NewBuffer(nil),
        fastaChan:      fnaSequences,
    }
    // fasta format is:
    //
    // >sequenceID some comments on sequence
    // ACAGGCAGAGACACGACAGACGACGACACAGGAGCAGACAGCAGCAGACGACCACATATT
    // TTTGCGGTCACATGACGACTTCGGCAGCGA
    //
    // see https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?CMD=Web&PAGE_TYPE=BlastDocs&DOC_TYPE=BlastHelp
    // section 1 for details
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(inputSequence)
Loop:
    for scanner.Scan() {

        line := scanner.Bytes()
        if len(line) == 0 {
            continue
        }
        if line[0] == '>' {

            if feeder.idBuffer.Len() > 0 {
                select {
                case <-ctx.Done():
                    break Loop
                default:
                }
                feeder.sendFasta()
            }
            feeder.reset()

            // parse the ID of the sequence. ID is formatted like this:
            // >sequenceID comments
            seqID := bytes.SplitN(line, []byte{' '}, 2)
            feeder.idBuffer.Write(seqID[0])

            if len(seqID) > 1 {
                feeder.commentBuffer.WriteByte(' ')
                feeder.commentBuffer.Write(seqID[1])
            }
        } else {
            // if the line doesn't start with '>', then it's a part of the
            // nucleotide sequence, so write it to the buffer
            feeder.sequenceBuffer.Write(line)
        }
    }
    // don't forget to push last sequence
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
    default:
        feeder.sendFasta()
    }
    close(fnaSequences)
}

// a type to hold an encoded fasta sequence
//
//  s[0:4] stores the size of the sequence id + the size of the comment as an uint32 (little endian)
//  s[4:idSize] stores the sequence id, and the comment id there is one
//  s[idSize:] stores the nucl sequence
type encodedSequence []byte

var pool = sync.Pool{
    New: func() interface{} {
        return make(encodedSequence, 512)
    },
}

func getSizedSlice(idSize, requiredSize int) encodedSequence {
    s := pool.Get().(encodedSequence)
    binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(s[0:4], uint32(idSize))

    for len(s) < requiredSize {
        s = append(s, byte(0))
    }
    return s[0:requiredSize]
}

func (f *fastaChannelFeeder) sendFasta() {

    idSize := 4 + f.idBuffer.Len() + f.commentBuffer.Len()
    requiredSize := idSize + f.sequenceBuffer.Len()

    s := getSizedSlice(idSize, requiredSize)

    if f.commentBuffer.Len() > 0 {
        copy(s[idSize-f.commentBuffer.Len():idSize], f.commentBuffer.Bytes())
    }

    copy(s[4:4+f.idBuffer.Len()], f.idBuffer.Bytes())

    // convert the sequence of bytes to an array of uint8 codes,
    // so a codon (3 nucleotides | 3 bytes ) can be represented
    // as an uint32
    for i, b := range f.sequenceBuffer.Bytes() {

        switch b {
        case 'A':
            s[i+idSize] = aCode
        case 'C':
            s[i+idSize] = cCode
        case 'G':
            s[i+idSize] = gCode
        case 'T', 'U':
            s[i+idSize] = tCode
        case 'N':
            s[i+idSize] = nCode
        default:
            fmt.Printf("WARNING: invalid char in sequence %s: %s, ignoring", s[4:4+idSize], string(b))
        }
    }
    f.fastaChan <- s
}

type fastaChannelFeeder struct {
    idBuffer, commentBuffer, sequenceBuffer *bytes.Buffer
    fastaChan                               chan encodedSequence
}

func (f *fastaChannelFeeder) reset() {
    f.idBuffer.Reset()
    f.sequenceBuffer.Reset()
    f.commentBuffer.Reset()
}
```

Answer (score 9):

This covers an interesting topic. Great work!

Because I am unfamiliar with this area, I utilized your unit testing to ensure changes I make did not break functionality. If they do, I apologize and please let me know.

### Utilize implicit repetition and `iota`

Rather than manually defining the type and value of `nCode`, `aCode`, etc. we an implicitly get the value using [`iota`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Iota). This also simplifies the assignment of `arrayCodeSize`.

```
const (
    nCode = uint8(0)
    aCode = uint8(1)
    cCode = uint8(2)
    tCode = uint8(3)
    uCode = uint8(3)
    gCode = uint8(4)

    stopByte = '*'
    unknown  = 'X'
    // Length of the array to store code/bytes
    // uses gCode because it's the biggest uint8 of all codes
    arrayCodeSize = (uint32(gCode) | uint32(gCode)<<8 | uint32(gCode)<<16) + 1
)
```

Becomes:

```
const (
    nCode = iota
    aCode
    cCode
    tCode
    uCode
    gCode

    stopByte = '*'
    unknown  = 'X'

    // Length of the array to store code/bytes
    // uses gCode because it's the biggest of all codes
    arrayCodeSize = (gCode | gCode<<8 | gCode<<16) + 1
)
```

### Check `error` return values

There are fourteen places in your code where the `error` return value is unchecked. If this is intentional, it's common practice to assign it to the [blank identifier](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blank_identifier): `_`.

Here is a list of occurrences:

- <s>`w.buf.WriteByte()` in `addByte()`</s>
- <s>`w.buf.WriteByte()` in `addUnknown()`</s>
- <s>`w.buf.WriteByte()` in `newLine()`</s>
- <s>Many `Write` and `WriteByte` calls in `Translate()`</s>
- <s>`feeder.idBuffer.Write()` and such, in `readSequenceFromFasta`</s>

**Update:** These always return `nil`.

### Reduce complexity of `Translate()`

The `Translate()` function is complex. It's current cyclomatic complexity is 45. (By the end of this, it's complexity is 27).

I notice that you define a `go` statement, which acts as a worker. I will leave it up to you to choose a fitting name, but for now "`worker()`" is sufficient.

```
func worker(wg *sync.WaitGroup, fnaSequences chan encodedSequence,
    ctx context.Context, framesToGenerate []int, arrayCode []byte,
    options Options, reverse bool, out io.Writer, errs chan error,
    cancel context.CancelFunc) {
    defer wg.Done()

    startPosition := make([]int, 3)

    w := &writer{
        buf:            bytes.NewBuffer(nil),
        bytesToTrim:    0,
        currentLineLen: 0,
    }

    for sequence := range fnaSequences {

        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return
        default:
        }

        frameIndex := 0
        startPosition[0], startPosition[1], startPosition[2] = 0, 1, 2

        idSize := int(binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(sequence[0:4]))
        nuclSeqLength := len(sequence) - idSize

    Translate:
        for _, startPos := range startPosition {

            if framesToGenerate[frameIndex] == 0 {
                frameIndex++
                continue
            }

            // sequence id should look like
            // >sequenceID_<frame> comment
            idEnd := bytes.IndexByte(sequence[4:idSize], ' ')
            if idEnd != -1 {
                w.buf.Write(sequence[4 : 4+idEnd])
                w.buf.WriteByte('_')
                w.buf.WriteByte(suffixes[frameIndex])
                w.buf.Write(sequence[4+idEnd : idSize])
            } else {
                w.buf.Write(sequence[4:idSize])
                w.buf.WriteByte('_')
                w.buf.WriteByte(suffixes[frameIndex])
            }
            w.newLine()

            // if in trim mode, nb of bytes to trim (nb of successive 'X', '*' and '\n'
            // from right end of the sequence)
            w.bytesToTrim = 0
            w.currentLineLen = 0

            // read the sequence 3 letters at a time, starting at a specific position
            // corresponding to the frame
            for pos := startPos + 2 + idSize; pos < len(sequence); pos += 3 {

                if w.currentLineLen == maxLineSize {
                    w.newLine()
                }
                // create an uint32 from the codon, to retrieve the corresponding
                // AA from the map
                codonCode := uint32(sequence[pos-2]) | uint32(sequence[pos-1])<<8 | uint32(sequence[pos])<<16

                b := arrayCode[codonCode]
                if b != byte(0) {
                    w.addByte(b)
                } else {
                    w.addUnknown()
                }
            }

            // the last codon is only 2 nucleotid long, try to guess
            // the corresponding AA
            if (nuclSeqLength-startPos)%3 == 2 {

                if w.currentLineLen == maxLineSize {
                    w.newLine()
                }
                codonCode := uint32(sequence[len(sequence)-2]) | uint32(sequence[len(sequence)-1])<<8

                b := arrayCode[codonCode]
                if b != byte(0) {
                    w.addByte(b)
                } else {
                    w.addUnknown()
                }
            }

            // the last codon is only 1 nucleotid long, no way to guess
            // the corresponding AA
            if (nuclSeqLength-startPos)%3 == 1 {
                if w.currentLineLen == maxLineSize {
                    w.newLine()
                }
                w.addUnknown()
            }

            if options.Trim && w.bytesToTrim > 0 {
                // remove the last bytesToTrim bytes of the buffer
                // as they are 'X', '*' or '\n'
                w.buf.Truncate(w.buf.Len() - w.bytesToTrim)
                w.currentLineLen -= w.bytesToTrim
            }

            if w.currentLineLen != 0 {
                w.newLine()
            }
            frameIndex++
        }

        if reverse && frameIndex < 6 {

            // get the complementary sequence.
            // Basically, switch
            //   A <-> T
            //   C <-> G
            // N is not modified
            for i, n := range sequence[idSize:] {

                switch n {
                case aCode:
                    sequence[i+idSize] = tCode
                case tCode:
                    // handle both tCode and uCode
                    sequence[i+idSize] = aCode
                case cCode:
                    sequence[i+idSize] = gCode
                case gCode:
                    sequence[i+idSize] = cCode
                default:
                    //case N -> leave it
                }
            }
            // reverse the sequence
            for i, j := idSize, len(sequence)-1; i < j; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
                sequence[i], sequence[j] = sequence[j], sequence[i]
            }

            if !options.Alternative {
                // Staden convention: Frame -1 is the reverse-complement of the sequence
                // having the same codon phase as frame 1. Frame -2 is the same phase as
                // frame 2. Frame -3 is the same phase as frame 3
                //
                // use the matrix to keep track of the forward frame as it depends on the
                // length of the sequence
                switch nuclSeqLength % 3 {
                case 0:
                    startPosition[0], startPosition[1], startPosition[2] = 0, 2, 1
                case 1:
                    startPosition[0], startPosition[1], startPosition[2] = 1, 0, 2
                case 2:
                    startPosition[0], startPosition[1], startPosition[2] = 2, 1, 0
                }
            }
            // run the same loop, but with the reverse-complemented sequence
            goto Translate
        }

        if w.buf.Len() > maxBufferSize {
            _, err := out.Write(w.buf.Bytes())
            if err != nil {
                select {
                case errs <- fmt.Errorf("fail to write to output file: %v", err):
                default:
                }
                cancel()
                return
            }
            w.buf.Reset()
        }
        pool.Put(sequence)
    }

    if w.buf.Len() > 0 {
        _, err := out.Write(w.buf.Bytes())
        if err != nil {
            select {
            case errs <- fmt.Errorf("fail to write to output file: %v", err):
            default:
            }
            cancel()
            return
        }
    }
}
```

But that's a ton of arguments for the worker, can more be done? Sure! But first, let's get rid of `goto`.

### `goto`

You use a `goto` statement to re-run a block of code again. That says to me: recursive function.

So, let's move this to a separate function. Again, I have no idea the proper name, and will leave that to you. For now, I'll call it `getComplexityAndReverse()` -- a verbose name, but it should suffice.

```
func getComplexityAndAlternate(startPosition []int, framesToGenerate []int,
    frameIndex int, sequence encodedSequence, idSize int, w writer,
    arrayCode []byte, nuclSeqLength int, options Options, reverse bool) {
    for _, startPos := range startPosition {
        if framesToGenerate[frameIndex] == 0 {
            frameIndex++
            continue
        }

        // sequence id should look like
        // >sequenceID_<frame> comment
        idEnd := bytes.IndexByte(sequence[4:idSize], ' ')
        if idEnd != -1 {
            w.buf.Write(sequence[4 : 4+idEnd])
            w.buf.WriteByte('_')
            w.buf.WriteByte(suffixes[frameIndex])
            w.buf.Write(sequence[4+idEnd : idSize])
        } else {
            w.buf.Write(sequence[4:idSize])
            w.buf.WriteByte('_')
            w.buf.WriteByte(suffixes[frameIndex])
        }
        w.newLine()

        // if in trim mode, nb of bytes to trim (nb of successive 'X', '*' and '\n'
        // from right end of the sequence)
        w.bytesToTrim = 0
        w.currentLineLen = 0

        // read the sequence 3 letters at a time, starting at a specific position
        // corresponding to the frame
        for pos := startPos + 2 + idSize; pos < len(sequence); pos += 3 {

            if w.currentLineLen == maxLineSize {
                w.newLine()
            }
            // create an uint32 from the codon, to retrieve the corresponding
            // AA from the map
            codonCode := uint32(sequence[pos-2]) | uint32(sequence[pos-1])<<8 | uint32(sequence[pos])<<16

            b := arrayCode[codonCode]
            if b != byte(0) {
                w.addByte(b)
            } else {
                w.addUnknown()
            }
        }

        // the last codon is only 2 nucleotid long, try to guess
        // the corresponding AA
        if (nuclSeqLength-startPos)%3 == 2 {

            if w.currentLineLen == maxLineSize {
                w.newLine()
            }
            codonCode := uint32(sequence[len(sequence)-2]) | uint32(sequence[len(sequence)-1])<<8

            b := arrayCode[codonCode]
            if b != byte(0) {
                w.addByte(b)
            } else {
                w.addUnknown()
            }
        }

        // the last codon is only 1 nucleotid long, no way to guess
        // the corresponding AA
        if (nuclSeqLength-startPos)%3 == 1 {
            if w.currentLineLen == maxLineSize {
                w.newLine()
            }
            w.addUnknown()
        }

        if options.Trim && w.bytesToTrim > 0 {
            // remove the last bytesToTrim bytes of the buffer
            // as they are 'X', '*' or '\n'
            w.buf.Truncate(w.buf.Len() - w.bytesToTrim)
            w.currentLineLen -= w.bytesToTrim
        }

        if w.currentLineLen != 0 {
            w.newLine()
        }
        frameIndex++
    }

    if reverse && frameIndex < 6 {

        // get the complementary sequence.
        // Basically, switch
        //   A <-> T
        //   C <-> G
        // N is not modified
        for i, n := range sequence[idSize:] {

            switch n {
            case aCode:
                sequence[i+idSize] = tCode
            case tCode:
                // handle both tCode and uCode
                sequence[i+idSize] = aCode
            case cCode:
                sequence[i+idSize] = gCode
            case gCode:
                sequence[i+idSize] = cCode
            default:
                //case N -> leave it
            }
        }
        // reverse the sequence
        for i, j := idSize, len(sequence)-1; i < j; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
            sequence[i], sequence[j] = sequence[j], sequence[i]
        }

        if !options.Alternative {
            // Staden convention: Frame -1 is the reverse-complement of the sequence
            // having the same codon phase as frame 1. Frame -2 is the same phase as
            // frame 2. Frame -3 is the same phase as frame 3
            //
            // use the matrix to keep track of the forward frame as it depends on the
            // length of the sequence
            switch nuclSeqLength % 3 {
            case 0:
                startPosition[0], startPosition[1], startPosition[2] = 0, 2, 1
            case 1:
                startPosition[0], startPosition[1], startPosition[2] = 1, 0, 2
            case 2:
                startPosition[0], startPosition[1], startPosition[2] = 2, 1, 0
            }
        }
        // run the same loop, but with the reverse-complemented sequence
        getComplexityAndAlternate(startPosition, framesToGenerate, frameIndex,
            sequence, idSize, w, arrayCode, nuclSeqLength, options, reverse)
    }
}
```

And we can simplify `worker()` even more:

```
func worker(wg *sync.WaitGroup, fnaSequences chan encodedSequence,
    ctx context.Context, framesToGenerate []int, arrayCode []byte,
    options Options, reverse bool, out io.Writer, errs chan error,
    cancel context.CancelFunc) {
    defer wg.Done()

    startPosition := make([]int, 3)

    w := &writer{
        buf:            bytes.NewBuffer(nil),
        bytesToTrim:    0,
        currentLineLen: 0,
    }

    for sequence := range fnaSequences {

        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return
        default:
        }

        frameIndex := 0
        startPosition[0], startPosition[1], startPosition[2] = 0, 1, 2

        idSize := int(binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(sequence[0:4]))
        nuclSeqLength := len(sequence) - idSize

        getComplexityAndAlternate(startPosition, framesToGenerate, frameIndex,
            sequence, idSize, *w, arrayCode, nuclSeqLength, options, reverse)

        if w.buf.Len() > maxBufferSize {
            _, err := out.Write(w.buf.Bytes())
            if err != nil {
                select {
                case errs <- fmt.Errorf("fail to write to output file: %v", err):
                default:
                }
                cancel()
                return
            }
            w.buf.Reset()
        }
        pool.Put(sequence)
    }

    if w.buf.Len() > 0 {
        _, err := out.Write(w.buf.Bytes())
        if err != nil {
            select {
            case errs <- fmt.Errorf("fail to write to output file: %v", err):
            default:
            }
            cancel()
            return
        }
    }
}
```

But, there's still loads of long arguments. However, now that things are broken into functions, I recommend shortening these variable names. These long names make the code very verbose.

With my limited knowledge, I see the following:

- `fnaSequences` → `fnaSeqs`
- `framesToGenerate` → `frames`
- `arrayCode` → `codes` (†)
- `startPosition` → `starts` (or `sPos`)
- `sequence` → `s` (changed in some places)

† This may be incorrect jargon.

### Move things to the lowest scope

For example, `startPosition` (now `starts`) can be declared in a lower scope.

While we're at it, `starts` can be declared as such:

```
starts := []int{0, 1, 2}
```

Resulting in:

(Within `worker()`)

```
for sequence := range fnaSequences {

    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        return
    default:
    }

    frameIndex := 0
    starts := []int{0, 1, 2}

    idSize := int(binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(sequence[0:4]))
    nuclSeqLength := len(sequence) - idSize

    getComplexityAndAlternate(starts, framesToGenerate, frameIndex,
        sequence, idSize, *w, arrayCode, nuclSeqLength, options, reverse)

    if w.buf.Len() > maxBufferSize {
        _, err := out.Write(w.buf.Bytes())
        if err != nil {
            select {
            case errs <- fmt.Errorf("fail to write to output file: %v", err):
            default:
            }
            cancel()
            return
        }
        w.buf.Reset()
    }
    pool.Put(sequence)
}
```

(Within `getComplexityAndAlternate()`)

```
if !options.Alternative {
    // Staden convention: Frame -1 is the reverse-complement of the sequence
    // having the same codon phase as frame 1. Frame -2 is the same phase as
    // frame 2. Frame -3 is the same phase as frame 3
    //
    // use the matrix to keep track of the forward frame as it depends on the
    // length of the sequence
    switch nuclSeqLength % 3 {
    case 0:
        starts = []int{0, 2, 1}
    case 1:
        starts = []int{1, 0, 2}
    case 2:
        starts = []int{2, 1, 0}
    }
}
```

### Duplicate code

The following code is used twice and should instead be a function:

```
_, err := out.Write(w.buf.Bytes())
if err != nil {
    select {
    case errs <- fmt.Errorf("fail to write to output file: %v", err):
    default:
    }
    cancel()
    return
}
```

Becomes a function (again, choose whatever name you want):

```
func writeOrCancel(w writer, out io.Writer, errs chan error,
    cancel context.CancelFunc) {
    if _, err := out.Write(w.buf.Bytes()); err != nil {
        select {
        case errs <- fmt.Errorf("fail to write to output file: %v", err):
        default:
        }
        cancel()
        return
    }
}
```

### Unroll short loops

```
case "F":
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        frames[i] = 1
    }
```

And

```
case "R":
    for i := 3; i < 6; i++ {
        frames[i] = 1
    }
    reverse = true
```

Shouldn't be loops. By using loops you use more magic numbers. Instead, unroll them:

```
case "F":
    frames[0] = 1
    frames[1] = 1
    frames[2] = 1
// ...
case "R":
    frames[3] = 1
    frames[4] = 1
    frames[5] = 1
    reverse = true
```

There's probably an even easier way to clean up the switch statement in `computeFrames()`.

### Don't name return arguments unless it simplifies code

In `computeFrames()` your return arguments are named, but they don't need to be.

### Use straightforward conditions

```
// generate 2 letter code
codes, ok := twoLetterMap[codon[0:2]]

if !ok {
    twoLetterMap[codon[0:2]] = []byte{aaCode}
} else {
    twoLetterMap[codon[0:2]] = append(codes, aaCode)
}
```

Is more clearly:

```
// generate 2 letter code
if codes, ok := twoLetterMap[codon[0:2]]; ok {
    twoLetterMap[codon[0:2]] = append(codes, aaCode)
} else {
    twoLetterMap[codon[0:2]] = []byte{aaCode}
}
```

### Exit loops early

You can break early upon the condition `codes[i] != codes[0]`.

```
for twoLetterCodon, codes := range twoLetterMap {
    uniqueAA := true
    for i := 0; i < len(codes); i++ {
        if codes[i] != codes[0] {
            uniqueAA = false
        }
    }
    if uniqueAA {
        first := letterCode[twoLetterCodon[0]]
        second := letterCode[twoLetterCodon[1]]

        uint32Code := uint32(first) | uint32(second)<<8
        resultMap[uint32Code] = codes[0]
    }
}
```

Becomes:

```
for twoLetterCodon, codes := range twoLetterMap {
    uniqueAA := true

    for _, c := range codes {
        if c != codes[0] {
            uniqueAA = false
            break
        }
    }

    if uniqueAA {
        first := letterCode[twoLetterCodon[0]]
        second := letterCode[twoLetterCodon[1]]

        uint32Code := uint32(first) | uint32(second)<<8
        resultMap[uint32Code] = codes[0]
    }
}
```

### Combine global `const` declarations

It's common practice to combine them, so readers of your code don't need to search the entire document.

### Move things to separate files

Your `writer` structure is relatively separate from everything else. I've moved it to a `writer.go` file -- moving the two constants it uses along with it.

You can also simplify the field names. If you feel explanation is needed, that's the purpose of documentation, not the field names themselves.

Rather than writing the following:

```
w := &writer{
    buf:    bytes.NewBuffer(nil),
    toTrim: 0,
    clen:   0,
}
```

We can use a `newWriter()` function, which follows Go APIs:

```
func newWriter(buf []byte) *writer {
    return &writer{buf: bytes.NewBuffer(buf)}
}
```

Also note that specifying the default values (`0`) is not needed.

### Conclusion: More to be done

I was not able to address all of the things I saw, but you should get the gist.

I would urge you to continue to break concrete operations into functions. Even though you may end up with lots of function arguments, in my opinion that's better than hard-to-read deep nesting and long functions. Perhaps once seeing how things break up, you can simplify the whole architecture of the package.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/esote/24e6c0e641e1af9502f1c3a0caf03c11) is a GitHub Gist of the final code. It includes other formatting things I did not mention explicitly.

Hope this helped. Your project looks promising, best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, there is some interesting ideas ! However, I disagree with a few points:

Comment: **(1)** can't use `iota` this way because `tCode` = `uCode` = `uint(3)` **(2)** `buf.Write()` and `buf.WriteByte()` always return a `nil`  error, cf [godoc bytes](https://godoc.org/bytes#Buffer.Write), so no need to check for it **(3)** I agree that high cyclomatic complexity is bad, but methods with **10 (!!)** arguments is not a good solution **(4)** `starts = []int{0, 2, 1}` allocates a new array instead of reusing the same slice. Not really sure it's worth it as it's in the hot spot of the code ! And this answer doesn't talk at all about the performance of the modified code

Comment: @felix **(1)** If you check, you will see that `tcode` is 3, and `ucode` is 4. That's how implicit repetition works in Go. **(2)** Fair point **(3)** In my opinion, it's better than code that's hard to read and understand, and definitely better than tons of nesting. If you split things into functions as I recommend, you may notice that functions (such as the one with 10 arguments) can be split up to do separate things. I left that work for you to implement. **(4)** If you do profiling, I highly doubt it will cause any noticeable performance difference.

Comment: I don't talk about the performance of the modified code because it's likely the same as before.

Comment: **(1)** sorry it wasn't clear enough, I meant both `tCode` and `uCode` have to be equal to `uint(3)` (cf initial code)

Comment: @felix Ah, sorry I didn't notice that originally. In this case, you can move it to be lower than the rest, and declare it as 3 or equal to `tCode`/`uCode`. When I was using your tests, it still passed with having different values, maybe there could be a way to check this.

Comment: I was curious, so I did some benchmarking on a small file with ~85.000 sequences. Here are the results on 100 iterations: `Translate-4     1.23s ±54%     1.33s ±59%  +8.57%  (p=0.000 n=99+100)` ( ie new code is 8.57% slower) I guess it' the cost of extra function calls

Answer (score 0):

After a large refactoring based on ideas from @esote answer, here is the result:

**gotranseq.go**

```
package transeq

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "sync"

    "github.com/feliixx/gotranseq/ncbicode"
)

// Options struct to store required command line args
type Options struct {
    Frame       string `short:"f" long:"frame" value-name:"<code>" description:"Frame to translate. Possible values:\n  [1, 2, 3, F, -1, -2, -3, R, 6]\n F: forward three frames\n R: reverse three frames\n 6: all 6 frames\n" default:"1"`
    Table       int    `short:"t" long:"table" value-name:"<code>" description:"NCBI code to use, see https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Taxonomy/Utils/wprintgc.cgi?chapter=tgencodes#SG1 for details. Available codes: \n 0: Standard code\n 2: The Vertebrate Mitochondrial Code\n 3: The Yeast Mitochondrial Code\n 4: The Mold, Protozoan, and Coelenterate Mitochondrial Code and the Mycoplasma/Spiroplasma Code\n 5: The Invertebrate Mitochondrial Code\n 6: The Ciliate, Dasycladacean and Hexamita Nuclear Code\n 9: The Echinoderm and Flatworm Mitochondrial Code\n 10: The Euplotid Nuclear Code\n 11: The Bacterial, Archaeal and Plant Plastid Code\n 12: The Alternative Yeast Nuclear Code\n 13: The Ascidian Mitochondrial Code\n 14: The Alternative Flatworm Mitochondrial Code\n16: Chlorophycean Mitochondrial Code\n 21: Trematode Mitochondrial Code\n22: Scenedesmus obliquus Mitochondrial Code\n 23: Thraustochytrium Mitochondrial Code\n 24: Pterobranchia Mitochondrial Code\n 25: Candidate Division SR1 and Gracilibacteria Code\n 26: Pachysolen tannophilus Nuclear Code\n 29: Mesodinium Nuclear\n 30: Peritrich Nuclear\n" default:"0"`
    Clean       bool   `short:"c" long:"clean" description:"Replace stop codon '*' by 'X'"`
    Alternative bool   `short:"a" long:"alternative" description:"Define frame '-1' as using the set of codons starting with the last codon of the sequence"`
    Trim        bool   `short:"T" long:"trim" description:"Removes all 'X' and '*' characters from the right end of the translation. The trimming process starts at the end and continues until the next character is not a 'X' or a '*'"`
    NumWorker   int    `short:"n" long:"numcpu" value-name:"<n>" description:"Number of threads to use, default is number of CPU"`
}

const (
    // nCode has to be 0 in order to compute two-letters code
    nCode uint8 = iota
    aCode
    cCode
    tCode
    gCode
    uCode = tCode

    // Length of the array to store codon <-> AA correspondance
    // uses gCode because it's the biggest uint8 of all codes
    arrayCodeSize = (uint32(gCode) | uint32(gCode)<<8 | uint32(gCode)<<16) + 1
)

var letterCode = map[byte]uint8{
    'A': aCode,
    'C': cCode,
    'T': tCode,
    'G': gCode,
    'N': nCode,
    'U': uCode,
}

func createCodeArray(tableCode int, clean bool) ([arrayCodeSize]byte, error) {

    var codes [arrayCodeSize]byte
    for i := range codes {
        codes[i] = unknown
    }

    twoLetterMap := map[string][]byte{}
    codeMap, err := ncbicode.LoadTableCode(tableCode)
    if err != nil {
        return codes, err
    }

    for codon, aaCode := range codeMap {

        if !(clean && aaCode == stop) {
            // codon is always a 3 char string, for example 'ACG'
            // each  nucleotide of the codon is represented by an uint8
            n1, n2, n3 := letterCode[codon[0]], letterCode[codon[1]], letterCode[codon[2]]
            index := uint32(n1) | uint32(n2)<<8 | uint32(n3)<<16
            codes[index] = aaCode
        }
        // in some case, all codon for an AA will start with the same
        // two nucleotid, for example:
        // GTC -> 'V'
        // GTG -> 'V'
        aaCodeArray, ok := twoLetterMap[codon[:2]]
        if !ok {
            twoLetterMap[codon[:2]] = []byte{aaCode}
        } else {
            if aaCode != aaCodeArray[0] {
                twoLetterMap[codon[:2]] = append(aaCodeArray, aaCode)
            }
        }
    }

    for twoLetterCodon, aaCodeArray := range twoLetterMap {

        aaCode := aaCodeArray[0]
        if len(aaCodeArray) == 1 && !(clean && aaCode == stop) {

            n1, n2 := letterCode[twoLetterCodon[0]], letterCode[twoLetterCodon[1]]
            index := uint32(n1) | uint32(n2)<<8
            codes[index] = aaCode
        }
    }
    return codes, nil
}

func computeFrames(frameName string) (frames [6]int, reverse bool, err error) {

    var frameMap = map[string]struct {
        frames  [6]int
        reverse bool
    }{
        "1":  {[6]int{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, false},
        "2":  {[6]int{0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, false},
        "3":  {[6]int{0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, false},
        "F":  {[6]int{1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, false},
        "-1": {[6]int{0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, true},
        "-2": {[6]int{0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, true},
        "-3": {[6]int{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, true},
        "R":  {[6]int{0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, true},
        "6":  {[6]int{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, true},
    }

    f, ok := frameMap[frameName]
    if !ok {
        return frames, false, fmt.Errorf("wrong value for -f | --frame parameter: %s", frameName)
    }
    return f.frames, f.reverse, nil
}

// Translate read a fata file and translate each sequence to the corresponding prot sequence
// with the specified options
func Translate(inputSequence io.Reader, out io.Writer, options Options) error {

    framesToGenerate, reverse, err := computeFrames(options.Frame)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    codes, err := createCodeArray(options.Table, options.Clean)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    fnaSequences := make(chan encodedSequence, 100)
    errs := make(chan error, 1)

    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    defer cancel()

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(options.NumWorker)

    for nWorker := 0; nWorker < options.NumWorker; nWorker++ {

        go func() {

            defer wg.Done()

            w := newWriter(codes, framesToGenerate, reverse, options.Alternative, options.Trim)

            for sequence := range fnaSequences {

                select {
                case <-ctx.Done():
                    return
                default:
                }

                w.translate(sequence)

                if len(w.buf) > maxBufferSize {
                    w.flush(out, cancel, errs)
                }
                pool.Put(sequence)
            }
            w.flush(out, cancel, errs)
        }()
    }
    readSequenceFromFasta(ctx, inputSequence, fnaSequences)

    wg.Wait()

    select {
    case err, ok := <-errs:
        if ok {
            return err
        }
    default:
    }
    return nil
}

// fasta format is:
//
// >sequenceID some comments on sequence
// ACAGGCAGAGACACGACAGACGACGACACAGGAGCAGACAGCAGCAGACGACCACATATT
// TTTGCGGTCACATGACGACTTCGGCAGCGA
//
// see https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?CMD=Web&PAGE_TYPE=BlastDocs&DOC_TYPE=BlastHelp
// section 1 for details
func readSequenceFromFasta(ctx context.Context, inputSequence io.Reader, fnaSequences chan encodedSequence) {

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(inputSequence)
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(make([]byte, 0, 512))
    headerSize := 0

Loop:
    for scanner.Scan() {

        line := scanner.Bytes()
        if len(line) == 0 {
            continue
        }
        if line[0] == '>' {
            if buf.Len() > 0 {
                select {
                case <-ctx.Done():
                    break Loop
                default:
                }
                fnaSequences <- newEncodedSequence(buf, headerSize)
            }
            buf.Reset()
            headerSize = len(line)
        }
        buf.Write(line)
    }

    fnaSequences <- newEncodedSequence(buf, headerSize)

    close(fnaSequences)
}
```

**writer.go**

```
package transeq

import (
    "bytes"
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "io"
)

const (
    mb = 1 << (10 * 2)
    // size of the buffer for writing to file
    maxBufferSize = 5 * mb
    // suffixes to add to sequence id for each frame
    suffixes    = "123456"
    maxLineSize = 60
    stop        = '*'
    unknown     = 'X'
)

type writer struct {
    codes            [arrayCodeSize]byte
    buf              []byte
    currentLineLen   int
    startPos         [3]int
    frameIndex       int
    framesToGenerate [6]int
    reverse          bool
    alternative      bool
    trim             bool
    // if in trim mode, nb of bytes to trim (nb of successive 'X', '*' and '\n'
    // from right end of the sequence)
    toTrim int
}

func newWriter(codes [arrayCodeSize]byte, framesToGenerate [6]int, reverse, alternative, trim bool) *writer {
    return &writer{
        codes:            codes,
        buf:              make([]byte, 0, maxBufferSize),
        startPos:         [3]int{0, 1, 2},
        framesToGenerate: framesToGenerate,
        reverse:          reverse,
        alternative:      alternative,
        trim:             trim,
    }
}

func (w *writer) reset() {
    w.frameIndex = 0
    if w.reverse && !w.alternative {
        w.startPos[0], w.startPos[1], w.startPos[2] = 0, 1, 2
    }
}

func (w *writer) translate(sequence encodedSequence) {

    w.reset()
    w.translate3Frames(sequence)

    if w.reverse {

        if !w.alternative {
            // Staden convention: Frame -1 is the reverse-complement of the sequence
            // having the same codon phase as frame 1. Frame -2 is the same phase as
            // frame 2. Frame -3 is the same phase as frame 3
            //
            // use the matrix to keep track of the forward frame as it depends on the
            // length of the sequence
            switch sequence.nuclSeqSize() % 3 {
            case 0:
                w.startPos[0], w.startPos[1], w.startPos[2] = 0, 2, 1
            case 1:
                w.startPos[0], w.startPos[1], w.startPos[2] = 1, 0, 2
            case 2:
                w.startPos[0], w.startPos[1], w.startPos[2] = 2, 1, 0
            }
        }
        sequence.reverseComplement()
        w.translate3Frames(sequence)
    }
}

func (w *writer) translate3Frames(sequence encodedSequence) {

    for _, startPos := range w.startPos {

        if w.framesToGenerate[w.frameIndex] == 0 {
            w.frameIndex++
            continue
        }
        w.writeHeader(sequence.header())

        // read the sequence 3 letters at a time, starting at a specific position
        // corresponding to the frame
        for pos := sequence.headerSize() + startPos; pos < len(sequence)-2; pos += 3 {
            index := uint32(sequence[pos]) | uint32(sequence[pos+1])<<8 | uint32(sequence[pos+2])<<16
            w.writeAA(w.codes[index])
        }

        switch (sequence.nuclSeqSize() - startPos) % 3 {
        case 2:
            // the last codon is only 2 nucleotid long, try to guess
            // the corresponding AA
            index := uint32(sequence[len(sequence)-2]) | uint32(sequence[len(sequence)-1])<<8
            w.writeAA(w.codes[index])
        case 1:
            // the last codon is only 1 nucleotid long, no way to guess
            // the corresponding AA
            w.writeAA(unknown)
        }
        w.trimAndReturn()
        w.frameIndex++
    }
}

// sequence id should look like
// >sequenceID_<frame> comment
func (w *writer) writeHeader(seqHeader []byte) {
    end := bytes.IndexByte(seqHeader, ' ')
    if end != -1 {
        w.buf = append(w.buf, seqHeader[:end]...)
        w.buf = append(w.buf, '_', suffixes[w.frameIndex])
        w.buf = append(w.buf, seqHeader[end:]...)
    } else {
        w.buf = append(w.buf, seqHeader...)
        w.buf = append(w.buf, '_', suffixes[w.frameIndex])
    }
    w.newLine()
}

func (w *writer) writeAA(aa byte) {

    if w.currentLineLen == maxLineSize {
        w.newLine()
    }
    w.buf = append(w.buf, aa)
    w.currentLineLen++

    if w.trim {
        if aa == stop || aa == unknown {
            w.toTrim++
        } else {
            w.toTrim = 0
        }
    }
}

func (w *writer) newLine() {
    w.buf = append(w.buf, '\n')
    w.currentLineLen = 0

    if w.trim {
        w.toTrim++
    }
}

func (w *writer) trimAndReturn() {
    if w.toTrim > 0 {
        w.buf = w.buf[:len(w.buf)-w.toTrim]
        w.currentLineLen -= w.toTrim
    }

    if w.currentLineLen != 0 {
        w.newLine()
    }
    w.toTrim = 0
}

func (w *writer) flush(out io.Writer, cancel context.CancelFunc, errs chan error) {
    _, err := out.Write(w.buf)
    if err != nil {
        select {
        case errs <- fmt.Errorf("fail to write to output file: %v", err):
        default:
        }
        cancel()
    }
    w.buf = w.buf[:0]
}
```

**encodedSequence.go**

```
package transeq

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

// a type to hold an encoded fasta sequence
//
// s[0:4] stores the size of the sequence header (sequence id + comment) as an uint32 (little endian)
// s[4:headerSize] stores the sequence header
// s[headerSize:] stores the nucl sequence
type encodedSequence []byte

func newEncodedSequence(buf *bytes.Buffer, headerSize int) encodedSequence {

    s := getSizedSlice(4 + buf.Len())
    // reserve 4 bytes to store the header size as an uint32
    headerSize += 4
    binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(s[0:4], uint32(headerSize))
    copy(s[4:], buf.Bytes())

    for i, n := range s[headerSize:] {
        switch n {
        case 'A':
            s[headerSize+i] = aCode
        case 'C':
            s[headerSize+i] = cCode
        case 'G':
            s[headerSize+i] = gCode
        case 'T', 'U':
            s[headerSize+i] = tCode
        case 'N':
            s[headerSize+i] = nCode
        default:
            fmt.Printf("WARNING: invalid char in sequence %s: %s, ignoring", s[headerSize:], string(s[headerSize+i]))
        }
    }
    return s
}

var pool = sync.Pool{
    New: func() interface{} {
        return make(encodedSequence, 512)
    },
}

func getSizedSlice(size int) encodedSequence {
    s := pool.Get().(encodedSequence)
    for len(s) < size {
        s = append(s, byte(0))
    }
    return s[:size]
}

func (s encodedSequence) header() []byte {
    return s[4:s.headerSize()]
}

func (s encodedSequence) headerSize() int {
    return int(binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(s[0:4]))
}

func (s encodedSequence) nuclSeqSize() int {
    return len(s) - s.headerSize()
}

func (s encodedSequence) reverseComplement() {

    headerSize := s.headerSize()
    // get the complementary sequence.
    // Basically, switch
    //   A <-> T
    //   C <-> G
    for i, n := range s[headerSize:] {
        switch n {
        case aCode:
            s[headerSize+i] = tCode
        case tCode:
            // handle both tCode and uCode
            s[headerSize+i] = aCode
        case cCode:
            s[headerSize+i] = gCode
        case gCode:
            s[headerSize+i] = cCode
        default:
            //case N -> leave it
        }
    }
    // reverse the sequence
    for i, j := headerSize, len(s)-1; i < j; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
        s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i]
    }
}
```